# Component identification: general semi LP 3C

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I have this component salvaged. I think it's very generic, but I cannot find it.

Properties:

- Dimensions: SMT 1206 length size, although the width is wider
- Logo: General Semi (now Vishay I think)
- Texts: Line 1: LP, Line 2: 3C
- One connection at each end
- PCB: Unknown

I would like to know what this is, as I cannot find any datasheet or identification.

[image]

Comment: The prominent bar on one end suggests teh cathode end of a diode. This page http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/lp suggests there are TVS diodes marked "LP", one of them by Vishay. Take a look at the datasheet there and see if it might eb a match (DO-214 etc)

Comment: Take a high value resistance, like 100k, in series with it. Apply 0-32vDC and measure voltage across the device. It will likely stop at some voltage, the clamping voltage.

Comment: @BrianDrummond DO-214 seems SMB, and mine is more like SMA, but your datasheet is closer than what I could find.

Comment: @rdtsc ... I will do (my power supply can only go until 30 V). ... Update: I will do, but not now, as I need to solder it to something (I have only two hands I cannot create that 'circuit'  including holding the multimeter etc.

Comment: Note do not test tantalum capacitors this way.  Doing so could destroy them.  We're sure this is a TVS though.

Comment: Ok I never tried it this way (or actually I barely used TVS's and never tested one), but I will do... I will solder one on a breakout board (when I have some more things to solder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this,](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf) 3C would be the date code.  LP is the type code.

[image]

According to [this,](https://www.google.de/url?q=https://www.vishay.com/doc%3F88392) LP is an SMBJ16A unidirectional Tranzorb TVS rated for 16 volts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... it seemed too small for SMB (but I don't have any reference).
16V could be useful too.